# Electrical potential with a combination of bodies

Tags: potential, electrical-engineering

1) what would occur with respect to electrical potential if a +1 charged body is brought close to a -2 charged body?

2) a positively charged body next to an earthed conductor

For the 1st one I'm not too sure to make an educated guess. For the second one I'm thinking that the positively charged body will lose potential due to induction while the earthed conductor will have a potential of zero ?

Comment: You may find this method helpful for the second problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) what would occur with respect to electrical potential if a +1
>   charged body is brought close to a -2 charged body?

The potential of -2 body will be getting less negative, while the potential of +1 body will be getting less positive. At some point, the potential of the +1 body will become zero and than negative. When the bodies get very close to each other, their potentials will be roughly equal (both negative) and become the same, when they get connected. The final potential will be negative, since the net charge will be -1.

In summary, the potentials of the two bodies will be getting closer to each other as the bodies get physically closer, until they equalize.

> 2) a positively charged body next to an earthed conductor

Your assumption regarding this case is correct. The general observation above will hold as well, i.e., the potentials of the two bodies will be getting closer to each other as they get closer, but, in this case, the potential of one of them won't be changing.